# More derived and less derived types

Tags: inheritance, covariance

Assuming we have class hierarchy `Object` <- `String` <-`Username` what class will be more derived and which one less derived ?

And if I declare interface like

```
interface IValidationRule<in T>
```

and my `T` is `String` does it mean I will be able to use `Username`, but not `Object` or otherwise?

Comment: You can't have that hierarchy, as `String` is sealed. I don't remember seeing the terms "more derived" and "less derived" in use very often - what's the context here?

Comment: Lets assume it is not sealed.

Comment: Why not come up with a more sensible example instead?

Comment: Context is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx "Contravariance enables you to use a 'less derived type' than that specified by the generic parameter."

Comment: And did the example with `Control` and `Button` make it clear? Or the example of `Person` and `Employee`? Why ask about another non-sensical example when there are already reasonable examples on the page you were looking at?

Comment: No, it did not. I prefer to clarify my doubts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I fail to see how asking about an impossible situation can help to clarify it - and if you just change your example to use `Person` and `Employee` or `Control` and `Button` (both of which are pretty clear) then the answer is right there on the page. If we were to just copy the words from MSDN into Stack Overflow, would that really have helped you? It would be a valid answer, IMO.

Comment: Yes, you failed. Please check nvoigt answer to see what you were to.

Comment: Just because there's an answer you're happy with doesn't mean it's a question worth asking - or that it's in *any* way helpful to give a nonsensical example. I content that with a bit more effort on your part, you could have found the answer for yourself by reading the documentation more carefully. It's all there.

Comment: I prefer someone else to do this job for me.

Comment: I would bet, since this question was asked, there have been one or two employers that had a similar preference, with a slightly different context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `Object` is the base class, anything derived from it (listed to the right) can be considered "more derived".

Comment: So "less derived" means going up in the hierarchy and "more derived" going down, right?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the second part of your question, since nvoigt already answered the first part.

Because `IValidationRule` is contravariant in its type parameter `T`, then `IValidationRule<object>` would be considered a subtype of `IValidationRule<string>`.

I.e., `IValidationRule<string>` <- `IValidationRule<object>`

Which means this would be possible:

```
IValidationRule<object> validationOfObject = //...
IValidationRule<string> validationOfString = validationOfObject
```

The opposite would of course not be valid.

In other words, if `A<T>` is contravariant, and `X` is a subtype of `Y`, then `A<Y>` is a subtype of `A<X>`.